# FilterChainProxy doesn't autowire

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-mvc, spring-security

I write so code:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//@WebAppConfiguration
public class CandidateControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;
    ...
}
```

Where I must write something that this code works?

stackTrace:

```
 ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@48834af6] to prepare test instance [controllers.CandidateControllerTest@23ae81ab]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controllers.CandidateControllerTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy controllers.CandidateControllerTest.springSecurityFilterChain; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanPr
....
```

I have bad understanding spring configuration. Please help.

**UPDATE**

post configuration files:

BeanConfig.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

        <!-- Включаем опцию использования конфигурационных аннотаций (@Annotation-based configuration)-->
        <context:annotation-config />


        <context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.hhsystem.jpa" />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.hhsystem.services" />

        <!-- Файл с настройками ресурсов для работы с данными (Data Access Resources) -->
        <import resource="data.xml" />

    </beans>
```

data.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<!-- Настраивает управление транзакциями с помощью аннотации @Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Менеджер транзакций -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Непосредственно бин dataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        p:url="jdbc:sqlserver://10.16.9.52:1433;databaseName=hhsystemTest;"
        p:username="userNew" 
        p:password="Pass12345" />

    <!-- Настройки фабрики сессий Хибернейта -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:test/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop> -->
        </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

what configurations needs for working my application?

Comment: Do you have the [`spring security`](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) jars available on the path? `FilterChainProxy` class is part of spring security

Comment: I have dependency for spring security in my project. security works in not test work variant

Comment: where is your spring security config ?

Comment: I must include it at this files?

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you haven't define that bean in your configuration.
You may try adding this

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <!-- properties -->
</bean>
```

And check whether you have included spring security in your project.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import your spring security context configuration xml file into your test.  This may be called securityContext.xml or may be part of your overall applicationContext.xml.  This xml file will contain "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd" or whichever version you are using.  To do this, modify the @ContextConfiguration annotation in your test as follows:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml", 
                                    "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class CandidateControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;
    ...
}
```

NB, "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml" may be different depending on your project setup.

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue. This was failing because I forgot to add (import) the security configuration. Once added it was able to autowire the FilterChainProxy correctly.

Comment: how to import security configuration? could you please show a piece of code